# Set the font for UIDatePicker in iOS10 with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uidatepicker

Is there is a public interface to set the **font** for a UIDatePicker in Swift 3?

I am well aware that similar questions have been asked, mainly asking about how to change the color of labels inside a UIDatePicker.

Using something like `datePicker.setValue(UIColor.someColor, forKey: "textColor")` is accessing a private property, which could raise some eyebrows.

And using `appearanceWhenContainedIn` doesn't expose neither the label's textColor nor its font:

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIDatePicker.self]).???
```

So, is there a *formal* way of changing the font of a `UIDatePicker`? Or should I build a date picker from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, is there a formal way of changing the font of a UIDatePicker?

No, there isn't. That is exactly why all these workarounds are proposed.