# Making UIDatepickerview font bold

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to make font of `UIDatepickerview` `bold` and did not find any way of doing it.

I can change color of font as follows

```
 timer.setValue(UIColor.white, forKey: "textColor")
 timer.setValue(false, forKey: "highlightsToday")
```

but I have no idea how to make font bold like `HeleveticaNeue-bold` with size `16`

Comment: You should not do this. Don't customize the iOS components using any private properties. This may lead to your app rejection. Instead, try to use some third party controls or create one for own need.

Comment: There is no way of doing it.
You can refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41793097/set-the-font-for-uidatepicker-in-ios10-with-swift-3?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks for the information @Hemang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For future References:**

> Although it is suggested to use the Native(Default) `UIDatePicker` of the Swift,
>   then also if anyone wants you can refer the following list

Following are some of the Customisable `Datepicker` from GitHub.

1. https://github.com/squimer/DatePickerDialog-iOS-Swift
2. https://github.com/itsmeichigo/DateTimePicker
3. https://github.com/hsylife/SwiftyPickerPopover
4. https://github.com/EngrAhsanAli/AAPickerView
5. https://github.com/dillidon/alerts-and-pickers
6. https://github.com/hughbe/day-date-picker
7. https://github.com/alikaragoz/AIDatePickerController
8. https://github.com/CooperRS/RMDateSelectionViewController
9. https://github.com/zhhlmr/ZHDatePicker
10. https://github.com/GasimGasimzada/FxDatePicker
11. https://github.com/anatoliyv/SMDatePicker
12. https://github.com/MarioIannotta/MIDatePicker

> **Note:** But yes do not Try to customise The appearance of `UIDatePicker`.As it might make a danger of rejection of your app in
>   future.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, and you should not do this.

Here's the relevant section from the UIKit documentation, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker

> **Appearance**
>
> The appearance of UIDatePicker is not customizable.
>
> You should integrate date pickers in your layout using Auto Layout.
>   Although date pickers can be resized, they should be used at their
>   intrinsic content size.

As Hermang suggests, if you need a customised version, you should use a third-party control, or customise your own, perhaps starting with `UIPickerView` - but that will mean a lot more work!

Comment: Appreciate the info, I will stick with defualt